# Keycloak docker

Tags: azure, keycloak, azure-container-instances

how can I deploy Keycloak docker in an azure container instance?
keycloak docker image that is provided by jboss/keyckloak keeps restarting in azure container instance after deployment. need help

Comment: Container is restarting for some reason, which you can find in the container logs. But you didn't provided them. Question needs more details.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to deploy keycloak in the Azure container registry. You can use jboss/keyckloak docker image. In my experience, reload might happen in case of resource luck or wrong configurations. Try to pick a bigger VM.

Comment: even the image from jboss/keycloack is not working fine with the azure container registry